# laravel many to many retrieve data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have many to many relationship and here's what I am doing:

In url I am passing businesses id which is in Business table:

```
@foreach ($business as $businesses)
        <a target="_blank" href="{{ url('business/' . $businesses->id) }}"> {{($businesses->name) }}
        </a> @endforeach
```

Then this function is ran:

```
public function displayBusiness($id) {
        $business = Business::find($id)->addresses;
        //return $business;
        //$address = Address::find($id);
        $session = session()->put('key', $id);
        $gallery = Gallery::where('business_id', $id)->get();
        $location = Location::where('business_id', $id)->get();
        $review = Review::where('business_id', $id)->get();
            return view('displayBusiness', compact('business', 'address', 'gallery', 'location', 'review'));
}
```

But the problem is the lines that are commented out, bring back results that match business id which is not always the case because sometimes business id = 1 and address id = 4 but this code will bring back address id = 1

So what I want to do is to look at my junction table that has business_id and address_id and use $id to find business_id as well as address_id that matches that id.

return business gives me []

So what I want is something like this:

Let's assume $id = 1
Go into business_address and find business_id that matches 1;
Also find address_id that matches business_id found,
Bring back matching id to business table and compact the results that match id
same for address table

my models:

Address.php

```
public function businesses() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Business::class, 'business_address', 'business_id', 'address_id');
}
```

Business.php

```
public function addresses() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Address::class, 'business_address', 'address_id', 'business_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing each business has many addresses. 
1. this would return the business with id of `$id`

```
$business = Business::find($id);
```

2. This would return All addresses matching that business

```
$address = $business->addresses;
```

Please note that the `$address` would return a *collection* not a *single object*
Let me know if this helps